# App Engine emulated datastore - strange observation

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I was experimenting with 'datastore' on my machine. Using this code.

```
            Key parentKey = KeyFactory.createKey("parent", "parentId");
            try {
    //          Entity parent = new Entity("parent", "parentId");
    //          parent.setUnindexedProperty("property1", "value1");
    //          ds.put(parent);
                Entity savedParent = ds.get(parentKey);
    //          savedParent.setUnindexedProperty("property1", "value3");
    //          ds.put(savedParent);
    //          Entity child = new Entity("child", "childId", savedParent.getKey());
                Entity child = ds.get(KeyFactory.createKey(savedParent.getKey(), "child", "childId"));
                child.setUnindexedProperty("property1", "val2");
                ds.put(child);
    //          logger.info("Saved child.");
            } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
```

First I saved parent entity and set property on it to "value2" then I added a child entity with property val1. Then I updated parent property to value3. Then I updated property on child to val2. 
Then I found out in the admin console, that value of the property on the parent is back to value2. I repeated it again with the same result. Am I missing something? Or is this some kind of bug?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, this is manifestation of eventual consistency, right? I run each step in a new JVM instance, thinking that values must have been stored at the time I switched it off:-. Contradicting common sense, but correct in terms of emulation of eventual consistency....